# Scala IDE is not working - scala could not find or load main class

Tags: scala

I try to run a simple scala spark program but somehow its throwing me a scala could not find load main class error. Any idea? 
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala Error: Could not find or load main class in both Scala IDE and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540135/scala-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-both-scala-ide-and-eclipse)

Comment: The image is not properly visible. Share the project structure and is it a sbt project ?