# Debugging a sbt project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a scala project cloned from github.

I can run it using:

> sbt 'path-to-module'/run

And it runs fine.

Now I want to debug it. How can it be done?Is there a similar sbt command for debug?

When I try to run/debug from Intellij's context menu for the object file containing main method(see image blow), I get message as:

> Error: Could not find or load main class

[image]

Comment: See 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540135/scala-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-both-scala-ide-and-eclipse
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?rq=1

Comment: did you try `Rebuild Project` under Build menu ? Sometimes intellij does not do it automatically. Try steps given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45486856/3287419

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try opening the sbt-shell (View|Tool Windows|sbt shell) and run a *compile* or even *clean* and *compile*.
You can, using sbt command start an application from this window too or even open the Scala REPL.

But once compiled you should be able to run the class.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the IntelliJ-internal  Virtual file system does not update its indexes on time when new files are generated. In this case it can help to ensure the class file exists via the built-in terminal and try to run it again.